# Estimating operators of functional linear processes

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-processes, operator-theory, time-series

Let $H= L^2[0,1]$ be the space of measurable and square integrable functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R},$ let $(\varepsilon_k)_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ denote the iid (or strict stationary) $H$-valued time series of innovations with $E(\varepsilon_0(t)) = 0$ and $E(\varepsilon^2(t)) = 1, \forall t,$ let $\alpha_0 = Id$ be the identity from $H$ to $H$ and let $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ...$ be linear and bounded operators from $H$ to $H.$ Further there is another time series $(X_k)_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ with

$$X_k = \sum_{l=0}^\infty\alpha_l(\varepsilon_{k-l}), \quad \forall k,\quad a.s.$$

Do you know a paper/book which deals with the estimation of the operators (with certain rates in sense of weak consistence [convergence in Probability])?

So far I just have found a theorem dealing with the realvalued case in "Time Series & Methods" - Theorem 8.3.1 from Brockwell & Davis.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Keyword: functional time series.

Comment: That doesn't really help :-)

Comment: This is the first link I get by googling the keyword: http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~shormann/hk2.pdf. It speaks about estimation and contains some links, which might be useful.

Comment: Thank you for you effort. This paper unfortunately deals with estimating the operator in the functional AR(1) model solely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the following paper from Aue and Klepsch from January:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.00770.pdf